# Elements hide behind .fixed-top navbar - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

I hope you're well, I would like to ask about some issue I've been having with Bootstrap, I've read the Bootstrap documentation and they state that .sticky-top might not be supported anymore by some browsers; and so because of that I decided to use .fixed-top instead, but, when I use this class, part of the body hides behind the navbar and I wonder is there is another way to fix this or the only way would to make it work would be adding a margin-top on CSS, as the .pt-5 class barely shows the content. As usual thank you so much for the help.

```css
:root {
  --body-font: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
  --main-font: "Caveat", cursive;
  --secondary-font: "Dosis", sans-serif;
  --primary-color: salmon;
  --secondary-color: rgb(71, 66, 65)
  --box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: var(--main-font);
  font-size: 22px !important;
}

.text-secondary{
  color: rgb(94, 94, 94);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="description" content="I'm Marizabelle Aldana, 27yo developer based in Guatemala, currently living in London.">

    <title>Marizabelle's website - Homepage</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&family=Anton&family=Caveat:wght@600&family=Dosis:wght@700&family=Roboto+Mono:wght@200&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

        <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

  <link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-secondary" href="index.html">Home</a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-secondary" href="about.html"
                >About me</a
              >
            </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link text-secondary" href="project.html">Projects</a>
                </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-secondary" href="about.html#email">Contact me</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
    <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
  </div>
</div>

    <div id="greeting">
      <img
        id="cat-icon"
        class="rounded mx-auto d-block pt-5"
        src="https://img.icons8.com/external-tulpahn-flat-tulpahn/64/000000/external-happy-cat-emoji-tulpahn-flat-tulpahn.png"
      />
      <br />
      <div class="sentence text-center">
        Hi
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An appropriate solution would be to add `padding-top` to the start of your main content based on the height of the fixed navbar. See the changes I made below.

I added fixed-height on `.jumbotron` only to test the scroll.

```css
:root {
  --body-font: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
  --main-font: "Caveat", cursive;
  --secondary-font: "Dosis", sans-serif;
  --primary-color: salmon;
  --secondary-color: rgb(71, 66, 65) --box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: var(--main-font);
  font-size: 22px !important;
}

.text-secondary {
  color: rgb(94, 94, 94);
}

.jumbotron {
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <meta name="description" content="I'm Marizabelle Aldana, 27yo developer based in Guatemala, currently living in London.">

  <title>Marizabelle's website - Homepage</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&family=Anton&family=Caveat:wght@600&family=Dosis:wght@700&family=Roboto+Mono:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-secondary" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-secondary" href="about.html">About me</a
              >
            </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link text-secondary" href="project.html">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-secondary" href="about.html#email">Contact me</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section style="padding-top: 4em;">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid position-relative">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
        <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="greeting">
      <img id="cat-icon" class="rounded mx-auto d-block pt-5" src="https://img.icons8.com/external-tulpahn-flat-tulpahn/64/000000/external-happy-cat-emoji-tulpahn-flat-tulpahn.png" />
      <br />
      <div class="sentence text-center">
        Hi
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add this style on body in index.css
padding-top = 70px;